# Scrollbar on svg zoom

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I am using D3 to create a visualization. The visualization fits well within the available canvas using viewBox

```
graphArea.attr("viewBox",bbox.x+" "+bbox.y+" "+bbox.width+" "+bbox.height);
```

This works great for smaller graphs. However, for some of the larger graphs, users need to zoom out the diagram for additional clarity.

When the user zooms out the diagram, parts of the diagram are hidden as they are outside the viewBox.

[image: Hidden diagram upon zoom]

My requirement is that, when user zooms out the diagram, a scroll bar is automatically provided which would enable the user to see the hidden parts by scrolling horizontally or vertically.

I tried dynamically setting the div width and height (which encloses the svg) but that did not help

```
d3.select("#containerdiv")          
 .attr('width', bbox.width)
 .attr('height', bbox.height);

});
```

Below is the complete code

```js
var width = 960, height = 400;
d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("id", "containerdiv");
// REMOVE OLD SVG
d3.select("#wkfsvg").remove();
var bbox = null;
     
// ADD NEW SVG
var graphArea = d3.select("#containerdiv").append("svg")   
            .attr({ width: width, height: height, "pointer-events": "all" })
   .attr("id","wkfsvg");


var g = new dagreD3.graphlib.Graph().setGraph({});

graphArea.insert("g", "g");

var nodesJson = [
    {
        
        "nodes": "Initiate",
        "status": "startend",
        "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Automatic"
    },
    {
       
        "nodes": "Find the Next Approver",
        "status": "completed",
        "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Automatic"
    },
    {
        
        "nodes": "Check for Manager",
        "status": "completed",
        "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Automatic"
    },
    {
        "nodes": "Set Status & ACL for IT Project Manager",
        "status": "completed",
        "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Automatic"
    },
    {
       
        "nodes": "Set Status & ACL for IT Sign Off Approvers",
        "status": "completed",
        "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Manual"
    },
    {
        
        "nodes": "IT Project Manager Approves",
        "status": "completed",
        "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Manual"
    },
    {
        "id": "Finance Approver",
        "nodes": "Finance Approver",
        "status": "dormant",
        "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Manual"
    },
    {
        
        "nodes": "Send Email for Completion",
        "status": "future",
        "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Manual"
    },
    {
       
        "nodes": "Send to Requestor",
        "status": "future",
        "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Manual"
    },
    {
        
        "nodes": "Send Email to Requestor",
        "status": "completed",
        "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Manual"
    },
    {
        "id": "Set ACL on Form for Requestor",
        "nodes": "Set ACL on Form for Requestor",
        "status": "future",
        "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Manual"
    },
    {
       
        "nodes": "Set Completion ACL on Form",
        "status": "future",
        "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Manual"
    },
    {
         "id": "Set Completion ACL on PO",
        "nodes": "Set Completion ACL on PO",
        "status": "future",
         "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Manual"
    },
    {
       
        "nodes": "Set Completion ACL on Attachments",
        "status": "future",
         "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Manual"
    },
    {
       
        "nodes": "Set ACL on Attachment",
        "status": "completed",
         "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Manual"
    },
    {
        
        "nodes": "Update Comments of PM Rejection",
        "status": "future",
         "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Manual"
    },
    {
        
        "nodes": "Update Comments of FA Rejection",
        "status": "future",
         "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Manual"
    },
    {
        
        "nodes": "Update Comments of PM",
        "status": "completed",
         "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Manual"
    },
    {
        
        "nodes": "Update Comments of FA",
        "status": "future",
         "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Manual"
    },
    {
        
        "nodes": "Update Comments of Requestor",
        "status": "future",
         "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Manual"
    },
    {
       
        "nodes": "End",
        "status": "startend",
         "creation_date": "",
        "performer_name": "",
        "execution_type": "Manual"
    }
];      
 

// Automatically label each of the nodes
nodesJson.forEach(function(node) {
   
    if(node.status == "future") {
        if(node.execution_type == "Manual") {
            g.setNode(node.nodes, { labelType: "html", label: node.nodes+' <tspan dx="0" dy="-10">\uf007</tspan>', class: "future" });            
        } else {
            g.setNode(node.nodes, { label: node.nodes, class: "future" }); 
        }
    } else if(node.status == "completed") {
        if(node.execution_type == "Manual") {
            g.setNode(node.nodes, { labelType: "html", label: node.nodes+' <tspan dx="0" dy="-10">\uf007</tspan>', class: "completed" });
        } else {
            g.setNode(node.nodes, { label: node.nodes, class: "completed" }); 
        }
    } else if(node.status == "dormant") {
       if(node.execution_type == "Manual") {
            g.setNode(node.nodes, { labelType: "html", label: node.nodes, class: "dormant" });
        } else {
            g.setNode(node.nodes, { label: node.nodes, class: "dormant" }); 
        }
    } else if(node.status == "startend") {
        g.setNode(node.nodes, { label: node.nodes, class: "startend" }); 
    } else {
        g.setNode(node.nodes, { label: node.nodes });
    }   
});

var edgesJson = [
    {
 
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Find the Next Approver",
        "target": "Check for Manager"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Check for Manager",
        "target": "Set Status & ACL for IT Sign Off Approvers"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Check for Manager",
        "target": "Set Status & ACL for IT Project Manager"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Set Status & ACL for IT Project Manager",
        "target": "IT Project Manager Approves"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Set Status & ACL for IT Sign Off Approvers",
        "target": "Finance Approver"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Set ACL on Form for Requestor",
        "target": "Send to Requestor"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Set Completion ACL on Form",
        "target": "Set Completion ACL on PO"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "IT Project Manager Approves",
        "target": "Send Email to Requestor"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Set Completion ACL on PO",
        "target": "Set Completion ACL on Attachments"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Set Completion ACL on Attachments",
        "target": "Send Email for Completion"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Initiate",
        "target": "Set ACL on Attachment"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Set ACL on Attachment",
        "target": "Find the Next Approver"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Update Comments of PM Rejection",
        "target": "Set ACL on Form for Requestor"
    },
    {
        "type": "reject",
        "source": "IT Project Manager Approves",
        "target": "Update Comments of PM Rejection"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Update Comments of FA Rejection",
        "target": "Set ACL on Form for Requestor"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Send Email to Requestor",
        "target": "Update Comments of PM"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Update Comments of PM",
        "target": "Set Status & ACL for IT Sign Off Approvers"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Finance Approver",
        "target": "Update Comments of FA"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Update Comments of FA",
        "target": "Set Completion ACL on Form"
    },
    {
        "type": "reject",
        "source": "Finance Approver",
        "target": "Update Comments of FA Rejection"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Send to Requestor",
        "target": "Update Comments of Requestor"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Update Comments of Requestor",
        "target": "Check for Manager"
    },
    {
        "type": "approve",
        "source": "Send Email for Completion",
        "target": "End"
    }
]; 

edgesJson.forEach(function(edge) {
    if(edge.type == "approve") {
        g.setEdge(edge.source, edge.target, { label: "" }); 
    }
    // Make the edge of rejected paths red and dashed
   if(edge.type == "reject") {
        g.setEdge(edge.source, edge.target, {
            label: "", class: "rejectEdgePath"
            
        });
    }
});



 var inner = graphArea.select("g");

// Set the rankdir
//g.graph().rankdir = "LR";
g.graph().nodesep = 10;


// Create the renderer
var render = new dagreD3.render();


// Run the renderer. This is what draws the final graph.
render(inner, g);

// Center the graph
/*var initialScale = 0.75;
zoom
  .translate([(graphArea.attr("width") - g.graph().width * initialScale) / 2, 20])
  .scale(initialScale)
  .event(graphArea); */
//graphArea.attr('height', g.graph().height * initialScale + 40);



bbox = graphArea.node().getBBox();
var selectedNode = inner.selectAll("g.node"); 
selectedNode.on('click', function (d) { 
    var nodeInfo = getNodeInfo(d);
    console.log('clicked '+nodeInfo.nodes+' (status: '+nodeInfo.status+')'); 
});

function getNodeInfo(name) {
    for (var i=0;i<nodesJson.length;i++) 
        if (nodesJson[i].nodes==name) return nodesJson[i]; 
}


console.log('bbox.x  '+bbox.x);
console.log('bbox.y  '+bbox.y);
console.log('bbox.width  '+bbox.width);
console.log('bbox.height  '+bbox.height);
graphArea.attr("viewBox",bbox.x+" "+bbox.y+" "+bbox.width+" "+bbox.height);
/*
d3.select("#containerdiv")   
     .attr('width', 200)
  .attr('height', 200);
*/

// Set up zoom support
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function() {
      inner.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" +
                                  "scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
   d3.select("#containerdiv")   
     .attr('width', bbox.width)
  .attr('height', bbox.height);
  
    });
graphArea.call(zoom);
```

```css
.node rect {
  stroke: #333;
  fill: #fff;
}

.edgePath path {
  stroke: #333;
  fill: #333;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.rejectEdgePath path {
  stroke: red;
  fill: red;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
  stroke-dasharray: 5, 5;
}



g.dormant > rect { 
  fill: #CC66FF;
}

g.completed > rect { 
  fill: #66FF99;
}

g.future > rect { 
  fill: #99CCFF;
}

g.acquired > rect { 
  fill: #EBBFFF;
}

g.paused > rect { 
  fill: #FF0000;
}

g.startend > rect { 
  fill: #CC6666;
}

foreignobject {
   fill: black;
   font-family: FontAwesome;
   font-size: 15px;
   text-anchor: middle;
//   cursor: move;
}
#wkfsvg {
    border: 1px solid BLUE;
        overflow: scroll;

}
#containerdiv {
    border: 1px solid RED;    

    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cpettitt.github.io/project/dagre-d3/latest/dagre-d3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated as I have hit the wall and totally clueless on how to proceed.

Thank you

Comment: Question is you need scroll-bar to scroll horizontally/vertically, when user zoomed-in. is this correct?

Comment: When it is not zoomed, the whole diagram fits within the canvas so no scrollbar would be necessary. However, this means that larger diagrams may be collapsed making it unreadable (depending on the size of diagram). So user would need to zoom out to read it properly but when it is zoomed, part of the diagram may go out of canvas. This is where a scrollbar would be needed.

Answer (score 4):

You are zooming by changing the `viewBox`.

If you want scrollbars, then you should leave the viewBox alone and change your svg `width` and `height` attributes instead.  That way you zoom by making your SVG render larger.  Then to get your scrollbars, set your container `<div>` to a fixed size and give it `overflow: auto`.

```js
var  zoomBtn = document.getElementById("zoom");
var  graphSVG = document.getElementById("graph");

var  zoomed = false;


zoomBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

   if (zoomed)
   {
     graphSVG.style.width = "100%";
     zoomBtn.textContent = "Zoom in";
     zoomed = false;
   }
   else
   {
     graphSVG.style.width = "200%";
     zoomBtn.textContent = "Zoom out";
     zoomed = true;
   }
  
});
```

```css
#container
{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}


#graph
{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" id="graph">
    
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="red"/>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="green"/>
  </svg>

</div>

<button id="zoom">Zoom in</button>
```

Comment: Thank you Paul. I changed the div to fixed width and height (with overflow auto) and set the svg width and height to 100%. However, when I zoom the diagram (using mouse scroll), scrolling is not enabled for the view outside the canvas (even though scrollbars are there). Am I still missing something?  Here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/94pgg33y/45/

Comment: You will need to adjust your zooming behaviour handler to alter your SVG width/height instead of applying a transform to a graph `<g>` element.

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you for the pointer. Is there an example that I could use?

Comment: Start by changing your zoom handler. It is currently adding a translate attribute to the 'inner' element.  Instead you want to multiply the `<svg>` width and height by `d3.event.scale`.  Later you may also want to improve the zoom behaviour by using the `d3.event.translate` value to adjust the scroll position of the container.

Comment: Presumably you don't want `#containerdiv` to resize, so you need to give it fixed dimensions. http://jsfiddle.net/94pgg33y/56/